# java cyclomatic complexity tools to use fully qualified class names

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

Most javancss tools use the method arguments as given in source code. The variable names are removed, but the class names are not FQN.

For example, given following class.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Demo {

    public void show ( java.io.File file) {
        //do some thing with file..
    }

    public void show2(File  win) {
        //do some thing with win
    }
}
```

Javancss  produce output

```
Nr. NCSS CCN JVDC Function
  1    1   1    0 Demo.show(java.io.File)
  2    1   1    0 Demo.show2(File)
Average Function NCSS:       1.00
Average Function CCN:        1.00
Average Function JVDC:       0.00
Program NCSS:                4.00
```

Note that the show2 comes with just File, not java.io.File
For my proeccessing, I require fully qualified names. Is there any ncss tools that could output FQN in reports?  (I tried cobertura's built in javacss and checkstyle.. all behaves the same way)

Edit (background) 
We now create cobertuta coverage report for each  method.   We want report on  methods with high complexity and lower coverage. When I tried to map CCN of method, the above case caused some difficulty. It was  (partially) solved by comparing only the class names not FQN.

Comment: Cyclomatic complexity measures how complex the control flow is in your program.  Why would fully qualified names make any difference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [CyVis](http://cyvis.sourceforge.net/index.html)?  From the [screenshots](http://cyvis.sourceforge.net/screenshoots.html) it appears to use fully qualified names.